# jquery keyup not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following function on keyup event to redirect to another javascript function.
Problem is it does'nt seem to fire, although it does bind the function to the textbox.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
EnablePickTargetButton();

//clear contents; use a delay because tinyMCE editor isn't always fully loaded on document.ready
var t = setTimeout(function () {
    if (typeof textEditorForCreate != 'undefined' && tinymce.editors.length > 0)
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('');
}, 300); 

var txtSearchUser = $('#txtSearchUser');
if(typeof txtSearchUser != 'undefined')
{
    $('#txtSearchUser').keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();                
            searchUser();
        }
        else
            alert('cucu');
    });
}
});
```

Not even the alert shows up. Checking the html, I can see it doesn't add onkeyup to the textbox; The textbox is in a popup window hosted in a div on the form; But on document.ready it runs the function without error.

Comment: Works fine on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e8JSA/ Have you added document.ready and included jQuery to the document?

Comment: How do you know it has bound to the box if it does not fire the event? @Anton comment seems to be the answer though.

Comment: @insertusernamehere The URL is jsFiddle main page

Comment: @Anton You beat me by 9 secs. :)

Comment: Yes work fine for me too http://jsfiddle.net/charaf11/nLYbX/ you may need to add ready() or your jquery is not loaded correctly

Comment: `.preventDefault()` doesn't seem to be working, here's the field is in a `<form>`: http://jsfiddle.net/vwqTR/

Comment: @Anton: I added this funciton inside document.ready. I edited the answer; I get no javascript errors, but it does'nt work

Comment: #Octavian Epure you have errors in your documents ready function check my answer

Comment: @Pietu1998 That's because the form is already send on `keydown`-

Comment: @OctavianEpure is `#txtSearchUser` dynamically added?

Comment: @insertusernamehere Yes, so if the `<input>` is in a `<form>` the `keyup` won't even be fired.

Comment: @Pietu1998 Actually it will, but not for the enter/return key.

Comment: @insertusernamehere That's what I meant.

Comment: When is `txtSearchUser` added? You noted that it's in a dialog. Is the HTML for this dialog generated in the javascript, and opened _after_ the page has loaded? Or is `txtSearchUser` already included?

Comment: @Pietu1998 I wasn't sure whether you meant every key or the specific from the OP. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this delegate on document or closest static element. (If the element is added dynamically)

```
$(document).on('keyup','#txtSearchUser',function(){
    //Code
});
```

Comment: Is there a way that i can find txtSearchUser and pass object through this delegate method's second parameter? When i tried that, it is not working i.e key up event not firiing

Answer (score 0):

it works :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#txtSearchUser').keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();                


        }
        else
            alert('cucu');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jMk5S/

check if you're referencing your html element properly. Perhaps you mix id with the class?

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code and is working :

The problem is in your document ready function , you have a syntax error , next time check console in your browser to see what's wrong :

### [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/charaf11/8UtWM/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//EnablePickTargetButton();

//clear contents; use a delay because tinyMCE editor isn't always fully loaded on document.ready
var t = setTimeout(function () {
    if ($('#textEditorForCreate').length != 0 && tinymce.editors.length > 0)
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('');
}, 300); 

if($('#txtSearchUser').length!=0)
{
    $('#txtSearchUser').keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();                
            searchUser();
        }
        else
            alert('cucu');
    });
}
});
```

Comment: `typeof txtSearchUser != 'undefined'` - absolutely useless check. jQuery instance can never be undefined. One need to check for `txtSearchUser.length`.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko i just corrected what's wrong so that script works,thanks for this advice i will mention it in the answer

Comment: @FaceOfJOck: I added my complete document ready function, there is no error there, I just didn't copy it okay to SO. I get no error in browser console.

Comment: @FaceOfJock: I found out why id doesn't work: this text box is in a dynamically added popup, so, at the time of document.ready, this test box isn't present in the html of the page; I tried adding a document.ready handler to the popup to bind there the event; doesn't work..